# View always in center of device screen

Tags: android

How can I create view which is always in center of device screen?

This view would be placed in some ViewGroup which has enough place for moving view.

Do I have to extend some class or always set position somehow?

**EDIT**

To explain something. Let's say we have activity with this very simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.75">

        <View
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my goal is to set View in the center of LinearLayout which is center of whole device.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Post your code. Your question is somewhat vague.

Comment: See edited question.

Answer (score 0):

set `layout_gravity` to `center` in xml

Comment: But parent view is not covering the whole screen.

Comment: i suggest use relativelayout as your parent view and add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in your child view